# How to AutoSave as Cell Value with Command Button click in Vba Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to add a second function with the click of the command button in Excel with VBA code - first function populates data from worksheet one (an order form) to a database log in worksheet two.  Looking for the second function to be carried out to be an auto-save with cell value from the order form.  Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo     As String, SKU As String
    Dim R As Long, LastSKURow As Long, NextDBRow As Long, OFrm As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet
    Set OFrm = Worksheets("Order Form 1")
    Set DB = Worksheets("Database")
    OrderDate = OFrm.Range("B3")
    PONumber = OFrm.Range("D3")
    Vendor = OFrm.Range("B7")
    ShipTo = OFrm.Range("D7")
    LastSKURow = OFrm.Cells(OFrm.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For R = 3 To LastSKURow
        SKU = OFrm.Range("F" & R).Value
        NextDBRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        DB.Range("A" & NextDBRow).Value = OrderDate
        DB.Range("B" & NextDBRow).Value = PONumber
        DB.Range("C" & NextDBRow).Value = Vendor
        DB.Range("D" & NextDBRow).Value = ShipTo
        DB.Range("E" & NextDBRow).Value = SKU
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,
        Path = "C:\PDF\"
        filename = OFrm.Range("D3")
        OFrm.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".pdf", FileFormat:=xlPDF
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

by auto-save do you mean that it saves the excel workbook? if so you could add something like this...

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

If this is not what you are looking for please let me know...

Comment: Mike,  Thanks for your feedback!  By auto-save, I mean I would like save the current order form worksheet (OFrm) to a pre-designated C: Drive location with the click of the Command Button that appears on the worksheet - not necessarily looking to save the entire workbook.  I, additionally, am looking for the file name to save as a cell value that appears in the worksheet.  Let me know what you can do!  The code is listed in the previous post from me above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it took a few days, I've been quite busy.

Based on your previous comment this subroutine that I wrote should resolve your problem. I chose to save the file as a pdf with the assumption that you've set a print area to your form. I chose a pdf because you stated it was an order form and the assumption is that the form will not be edited later. I opted to it because it was a form and there may be some calculated fields attached to another sheet which would not work if you detached the worksheet. If however you decide that you just want a copy of the worksheet I've included the code for it as well. All you need to do is fill in the areas with the comments and attach this function to a command button :). Please let me know if you would like additional information about how to do this.

For the pdf function you can see the information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-exportasfixedformat-method-excel

For the Save As information you can see the information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-saveas-method-excel

```
Public Sub savefile()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngfilename As Range
Dim strSavePath As String

'assumptions:
'you are saving the file to a fixed location and the name of the file within the range is continually changing
'you have set the print areas

Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set rngfilename = ws.Range("A1") 'the range that contains your filename
strSavePath = "C:/" 'the location that you would like to save your file

'ensure that there is a value within the filename field declared above
If rngfilename.Value = "" Or Len(rngfilename) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered a filename"
    Exit Sub
End If

'if you do not have print areas set ignore print areas to true in the function bellow
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strSavePath & rngfilename.Value, xlQualityStandard
'for the save as function
'ws.SaveAs strSavePathe & rngfilename.Value
End Sub
```